# Webcam, Wifi Card, Mini Mic from netbook into spycam

Tags: wireless-networking, netbook, sd-card

I got a Netbook from the recycling plant that the screen was trashed hardware was fine so I gutted it and am selling the hardware... but I liked the slim chip the webcam has and how small the mic is... I was wondering if I could put the 3 items to use together to make a spy cam type thing if I got a card reader chip. and if I can How would I go about learning HOW to do it.

Comment: How good are your soldering skills? Do you have any knowledge of electronics?

Comment: my soldering is fairly good I've replaced blow caps on full size motherboards before and the board worked fine after. I've been opening up the insides of computer since I was 10 and I just turned 25 on Dec 10th

Comment: I've had no actual training in making custom boards I've only stuck to preexisting hardware